# Clear the Scratch.gdb

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, scratch-workspace

I have created a script that produces multiple "temporary" tables (using the arcpy.statistics_analysis function). These temporary tables are exported to the %scratchGDB%, I would like to insert python code into my script at the very start of my script that clears the %scratchGDB% before the tool is run. When I try to re-run the tool without deleting out these temporary files / clearing the scratchGDB I get an error that the table already exists and cannot be exported. If there is a way to overwrite the table, that would also be helpful. My script is attached below for reference.

```
  # Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
BldgSpace_Feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Building_Floor_Area_Feature_Class = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Output_Table_Name_and_Location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)



# Local variables:
building_space_area = BldgSpace_Feature
BuildingSpace_A2 = r'%scratchGDB%/BuildingSpaceArea2'
BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1 = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgSpaceStatistics1'
BldgSpaceAreaStatistics2 = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgSpaceStatistics2'
BldgSpaceAreaStatistics4 = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgSpaceStatistics4'
BldgSpaceAreaStatistics3 = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgSpaceStatistics3'
BuildingSpaceStatistics = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgSpaceStatisticsRPUIDsum'
BuildingFloor_A_Layer = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgFloorMainStructureLayer'
BldgMainStructureAreaStatistics1 = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgMainStructureStatistics1'
BldgFloorNonMain = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgFloorNonMainLayer'
BldgNonMainAreaStatistics1 = r'%scratchGDB%/BldgNonMainStatistics1'
BldgSpaceArea = r'%scratchGDB%/BuildingSpaceAreaTypes'


# Process: Delete Any Applicable Fields of Input Feature Class
arcpy.DeleteField_management(BldgSpace_Feature, "CalculatedArea;CommonAndSpaceType;CommonIdentifier;UID")

# Process: Add Field - UID
arcpy.AddField_management(BldgSpace_Feature, "UID", "TEXT", "", "", "50", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate UID
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BldgSpace_Feature, "UID", "[realPropertyUniqueID] &\"_\"& [unit] &\"_\"& [dodCategoryCode]", "VB", "")

# Process: Summary Statistics 4 
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(BldgSpace_Feature, BldgSpaceAreaStatistics4, "UID COUNT", "UID;unit;realPropertyUniqueID;facilityID;dodCategoryCode")

# Process: SumAreaSize - UID - RPUID - SpaceDiscriminator
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(BldgSpace_Feature, BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "areaSize SUM", "UID;spaceDiscriminator;realPropertyUniqueID")

# Process: CreateSpaceTypeRPUID field
arcpy.AddField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "SpaceTypeRPUID", "TEXT", "", "", "50", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Combine SpaceDiscriminator with RPUID Statistics1 Table
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "SpaceTypeRPUID", "[realPropertyUniqueID] & [spaceDiscriminator]", "VB", "")

# Process: Calc Total RPUID Area
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(BldgSpace_Feature, BldgSpaceAreaStatistics2, "areaSize SUM", "realPropertyUniqueID")

# Process: Join Field RPUID Area and UID / RPUID / SpaceDiscriminator Area
arcpy.JoinField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "realPropertyUniqueID", BldgSpaceAreaStatistics2, "realPropertyUniqueID", "SUM_areaSize")

# Process: SumArea - SpaceDiscriminator - RPUID
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(BldgSpace_Feature, BldgSpaceAreaStatistics3, "areaSize SUM", "spaceDiscriminator;realPropertyUniqueID")

# Process: Create SpaceTypeRPUID Field
arcpy.AddField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics3, "SpaceTypeRPUID", "TEXT", "", "", "50", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Combine RPUID and SpaceDiscriminator
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics3, "SpaceTypeRPUID", "[realPropertyUniqueID] & [spaceDiscriminator]", "VB", "")

# Process: Join Field (2)
arcpy.JoinField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "SpaceTypeRPUID", BldgSpaceAreaStatistics3, "SpaceTypeRPUID", "SUM_areaSize")

# Process: Sum of RPUID
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(BldgSpace_Feature, BuildingSpaceStatistics, "areaSize SUM", "realPropertyUniqueID")

# Process: Select all Main Structure 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Building_Floor_Area_Feature_Class, "BuildingFloor_A_Layer", "floorType = 'mainStructure'", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;buildingFloorIDPK buildingFloorIDPK VISIBLE NONE;sdsID sdsID VISIBLE NONE;sdsFeatureName sdsFeatureName VISIBLE NONE;sdsFeatureDescription sdsFeatureDescription VISIBLE NONE;sdsMetadataID sdsMetadataID VISIBLE NONE;areaSize areaSize VISIBLE NONE;areaSizeUOM areaSizeUOM VISIBLE NONE;perimeterSize perimeterSize VISIBLE NONE;perimeterSizeUOM perimeterSizeUOM VISIBLE NONE;latitude latitude VISIBLE NONE;longitude longitude VISIBLE NONE;MGRScentroid MGRScentroid VISIBLE NONE;floorID floorID VISIBLE NONE;buildngID buildngID VISIBLE NONE;floorName floorName VISIBLE NONE;floorCost floorCost VISIBLE NONE;floorUseableArea floorUseableArea VISIBLE NONE;floorUseableAreaUOM floorUseableAreaUOM VISIBLE NONE;floorBusinessArea floorBusinessArea VISIBLE NONE;floorBusinessAreaUOM floorBusinessAreaUOM VISIBLE NONE;floorCommonArea floorCommonArea VISIBLE NONE;floorCommonAreaUOM floorCommonAreaUOM VISIBLE NONE;floorRentableArea floorRentableArea VISIBLE NONE;floorRentableAreaUOM floorRentableAreaUOM VISIBLE NONE;facilityID facilityID VISIBLE NONE;exteriorWallThicknessUOM exteriorWallThicknessUOM VISIBLE NONE;exteriorWallThickness exteriorWallThickness VISIBLE NONE;floorType floorType VISIBLE NONE;realPropertyUniqueID realPropertyUniqueID VISIBLE NONE;installationID installationID VISIBLE NONE;installationName installationName VISIBLE NONE;siteID siteID VISIBLE NONE;majorCommand majorCommand VISIBLE NONE;realPropertySiteUniqueID realPropertySiteUniqueID VISIBLE NONE;wacInnrCode wacInnrCode VISIBLE NONE;dataSteward dataSteward VISIBLE NONE;country country VISIBLE NONE;owner owner VISIBLE NONE;createDate createDate VISIBLE NONE;creator creator VISIBLE NONE;dataCollection dataCollection VISIBLE NONE;dataSource dataSource VISIBLE NONE;editor editor VISIBLE NONE;dateEdited dateEdited VISIBLE NONE;metaNotes metaNotes VISIBLE NONE;mediaLink mediaLink VISIBLE NONE;narrative narrative VISIBLE NONE;COORD_ID COORD_ID VISIBLE NONE;FLOORKEY FLOORKEY VISIBLE NONE;GLOBALID GLOBALID VISIBLE NONE;GRID_VALUE GRID_VALUE VISIBLE NONE;MAP_ID MAP_ID VISIBLE NONE;USER_FLAG USER_FLAG VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Length Shape_Length VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Area Shape_Area VISIBLE NONE")

# Process: Sum of all main structure area
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("BuildingFloor_A_Layer", BldgMainStructureAreaStatistics1, "areaSize SUM", "realPropertyUniqueID")

# Process: Join Field (5)
arcpy.JoinField_management(BuildingSpaceStatistics, "realPropertyUniqueID", BldgMainStructureAreaStatistics1, "realPropertyUniqueID", "SUM_areaSize")

# Process: AddField - Difference Btw Floor Main and RPUID Area space
arcpy.AddField_management(BuildingSpaceStatistics, "DiffFloorAreaSpaceArea", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calcs the diff btw Total floor area space from the bldgSpace RPUID
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BuildingSpaceStatistics, "DiffFloorAreaSpaceArea", "[SUM_areaSize_1]- [SUM_areaSize]", "VB", "")

# Process: Make Feature Layer (3)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Building_Floor_Area_Feature_Class, "BldgFloorNonMain", "floorType <> 'mainStructure'", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;buildingFloorIDPK buildingFloorIDPK VISIBLE NONE;sdsID sdsID VISIBLE NONE;sdsFeatureName sdsFeatureName VISIBLE NONE;sdsFeatureDescription sdsFeatureDescription VISIBLE NONE;sdsMetadataID sdsMetadataID VISIBLE NONE;areaSize areaSize VISIBLE NONE;areaSizeUOM areaSizeUOM VISIBLE NONE;perimeterSize perimeterSize VISIBLE NONE;perimeterSizeUOM perimeterSizeUOM VISIBLE NONE;latitude latitude VISIBLE NONE;longitude longitude VISIBLE NONE;MGRScentroid MGRScentroid VISIBLE NONE;floorID floorID VISIBLE NONE;buildngID buildngID VISIBLE NONE;floorName floorName VISIBLE NONE;floorCost floorCost VISIBLE NONE;floorUseableArea floorUseableArea VISIBLE NONE;floorUseableAreaUOM floorUseableAreaUOM VISIBLE NONE;floorBusinessArea floorBusinessArea VISIBLE NONE;floorBusinessAreaUOM floorBusinessAreaUOM VISIBLE NONE;floorCommonArea floorCommonArea VISIBLE NONE;floorCommonAreaUOM floorCommonAreaUOM VISIBLE NONE;floorRentableArea floorRentableArea VISIBLE NONE;floorRentableAreaUOM floorRentableAreaUOM VISIBLE NONE;facilityID facilityID VISIBLE NONE;exteriorWallThicknessUOM exteriorWallThicknessUOM VISIBLE NONE;exteriorWallThickness exteriorWallThickness VISIBLE NONE;floorType floorType VISIBLE NONE;realPropertyUniqueID realPropertyUniqueID VISIBLE NONE;installationID installationID VISIBLE NONE;installationName installationName VISIBLE NONE;siteID siteID VISIBLE NONE;majorCommand majorCommand VISIBLE NONE;realPropertySiteUniqueID realPropertySiteUniqueID VISIBLE NONE;wacInnrCode wacInnrCode VISIBLE NONE;dataSteward dataSteward VISIBLE NONE;country country VISIBLE NONE;owner owner VISIBLE NONE;createDate createDate VISIBLE NONE;creator creator VISIBLE NONE;dataCollection dataCollection VISIBLE NONE;dataSource dataSource VISIBLE NONE;editor editor VISIBLE NONE;dateEdited dateEdited VISIBLE NONE;metaNotes metaNotes VISIBLE NONE;mediaLink mediaLink VISIBLE NONE;narrative narrative VISIBLE NONE;COORD_ID COORD_ID VISIBLE NONE;FLOORKEY FLOORKEY VISIBLE NONE;GLOBALID GLOBALID VISIBLE NONE;GRID_VALUE GRID_VALUE VISIBLE NONE;MAP_ID MAP_ID VISIBLE NONE;USER_FLAG USER_FLAG VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Length Shape_Length VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Area Shape_Area VISIBLE NONE")

# Process: Summary Statistics (3)
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("BldgFloorNonMain", BldgNonMainAreaStatistics1, "areaSize SUM", "realPropertyUniqueID")

# Process: CalcFloorNonMain Structure area - multiplies by half
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BldgNonMainAreaStatistics1, "SUM_areaSize", "[SUM_areaSize] *0.5", "VB", "")

# Process: Join Field (6)
arcpy.JoinField_management(BuildingSpaceStatistics, "realPropertyUniqueID", BldgNonMainAreaStatistics1, "realPropertyUniqueID", "SUM_areaSize")

# Process: Calculate Field (4)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BuildingSpaceStatistics, "SUM_areaSize_12", "updateValue( !SUM_areaSize_12!)", "PYTHON_9.3", "def updateValue(value):\\n if value is None:\\n      return '0'\\n else: return value")

# Process: Add Field (3)
arcpy.AddField_management(BuildingSpaceStatistics, "SumTotalCommonSpace", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Field (5)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BuildingSpaceStatistics, "SumTotalCommonSpace", "[DiffFloorAreaSpaceArea]+ [SUM_areaSize_12]", "VB", "")

# Process: Join Field (7)
arcpy.JoinField_management(BldgSpace_Feature, "realPropertyUniqueID", BuildingSpaceStatistics, "realPropertyUniqueID", "SumTotalCommonSpace")

# Process: Join Field (8)
arcpy.JoinField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "realPropertyUniqueID", BldgSpace_Feature, "realPropertyUniqueID", "SumTotalCommonSpace")

# Process: Create Total Calculated Area Field
arcpy.AddField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "CalculatedArea", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Area
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "CalculatedArea", "(( [SUM_areaSize]/ [SUM_areaSize_12])*(([SUM_areaSize_1]- [SUM_areaSize_12])+ [SumTotalCommonSpace])+ [SUM_areaSize])", "VB", "")

# Process: Create Common Identifier Field
arcpy.AddField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "CommonIdentifier", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Common Identifier
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "CommonIdentifier", "[SUM_areaSize_1]/ [SUM_areaSize_12]", "VB", "")

# Process: Join Field (4)
arcpy.JoinField_management(BldgSpace_Feature, "UID", BldgSpaceAreaStatistics1, "UID", "CalculatedArea;CommonIdentifier")

# Process: Create Common Unique ID Field
arcpy.AddField_management(BldgSpace_Feature, "CommonAndSpaceType", "TEXT", "", "", "50", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Common and SpaceType
arcpy.CalculateField_management(BldgSpace_Feature, "CommonAndSpaceType", "[CommonIdentifier]& [spaceDiscriminator]", "VB", "")

# Process: Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(BldgSpace_Feature, BldgSpaceArea, "CommonAndSpaceType LIKE'1c%' OR CommonAndSpaceType LIKE'1b%' OR CommonAndSpaceType LIKE'%business'")

# Process: Join Field (3)
arcpy.JoinField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics4, "UID", BldgSpaceArea, "UID", "CalculatedArea")

# Process: Delete Field
arcpy.DeleteField_management(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics4, "FREQUENCY;COUNT_UID")

# Process: Table To Excel
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(BldgSpaceAreaStatistics4, Output_Table_Name_and_Location, "NAME", "CODE")

# Process: Delete Field (2)
arcpy.DeleteField_management(BldgSpace_Feature, "SumTotalCommonSpace;CommonAndSpaceType;CommonIdentifier;CalculatedArea")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to simply overwrite existing tables then set overwrite to be true at the beginning of your script as such:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

Personally I don't use those system variables such as `%scratchGDB%` as that is the system making a decision for you. Why not create a folder with a file geodatabase called fGDB_Scratch and read\write from that. At least you know where your data is going...

Comment: Thanks, seemed to do the trick! Unfortunately this script is going out to a field of users otherwise I would do just that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to clear a geodatabase of tables or feature classes.:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\TargetGeodatabase.gdb"

LocalTables = arcpy.ListTables()

for table in LocalTables:
    arcpy.Delete_management(table)
```

The example above is for tables, but if you change arcpy.ListTables() to arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() it will delete those instead.